# Accessing data in catalog_product_save_before observer

Tags: event-observer, magento-1, catalog

I created an catalog_product_save_before observer to update some attributes based on other attributes. Specifically, I use m2epro to update my ebay listings. Sometimes I want ebay to show less in stock than I actually have, so I created 2 new attributies, ebay_qty and ebay_max_qty.

In my observer, I have the following code:

```
$product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
$stock = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($product);

$Qty = $stock->getQty();
$EBayQty = $Qty;
$MaxQty = $product->getEbayMaxQty();

if (($MaxQty > 0) && ($EBayQty > $MaxQty))
    $EBayQty = $MaxQty;

$product->setData('ebay_qty', $EBayQty);
```

This is grabbing the qty currently in the database. How do I get the new Qty about to be saved?

Comment: Someone suggested I add a tag m2epro. I rejected the idea because this topic has nothing to do with m2epro, I only included that information to give some background info on why I'm attempting to do what I'm doing so I didn't get useless answers about different ways to do something I'm not trying to do. I'm actually doing a lot more than I show here, but I showed enough to get the answer I need and not confuse the question with unneeded information. Had the person attempted to help answer the question, I would have given their suggestion more credit.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like no one has the answer to this. After searching for hours, I'm wondering if its even possible. I'm guessing it is as if I do a var_dump($product), Qty is listed, but can't figure out how to access it.

I did find a work around that might help someone else. I added a second function to the class and is called by the `catalog_product_save_after` `observer`

The config.xml file now looks like this:

```
    <events>
        <catalog_product_save_before>
            <observers>
                <me_createebaydescription>
                    <class>me_createebaydescription/observer</class>
                    <method>ebayDescriptionUpdate</method>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                </me_createebaydescription>
            </observers>
        </catalog_product_save_before>
        <catalog_product_save_after>
            <observers>
                <me_createebaydescription>
                    <class>me_createebaydescription/observer</class>
                    <method>ebayQtyUpdate</method>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                </me_createebaydescription>
            </observers>
        </catalog_product_save_after>
    </events>
```

I used the `UpdateAttributes` function and added the following function to the observer:

```
public function ebayQtyUpdate(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();

    $ID = Array($product->getId());
    $UpdateData = Array('ebay_qty'=>$this->GetEBayQty($product));

    Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_action')
        ->updateAttributes($ID, $UpdateData, 0);
}
```

Comment: Please remove this answer and edit the other answer put all the information in a single answer, as if you were answering somebody else's question. Magento.SE is not a threaded discussion forum.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer incase anyone can't figure this out.
First, I found `catalog_product_prepare_save` was a better place to do this than `catalog_product_save_before`. Don't know why, but someone suggested it, it worked, so not questioning it.

What I was missing was

```
$request = $observer->getEvent()->getRequest();
$request->getPost('what you're looking for')
```

You can then override the submitted data before its saved with

```
$product->setYourAttribute($NewValue);
or
$product->setData('YourAttribute', $NewValue);
```